# Comparing every line of two text files

Tags: java, string, string-comparison, large-data

I have one text file A with ~300 lines and one text file B with ~30000 lines.

Now, I have a method which takes two lines and returns the Levenshtein distance. Each line of B must be compared with each line of A and the shortest Levenshtein distance must be stored somewhere with reference to the line in file A.

Since in this situation every single line of one file must be compared with every single line of the other file,
the only way I can think of is using two nested for loops, storing the output of my method in an array for each line of file B (so ~30000 arrays) then calling a min method on each array.

This is practically impossible because java runs out of memory very soon.

Is there a more efficient method to accomplish said thing?

Comment: Why can't you keep the *current* minimum only (shortest distance)?

Comment: Why store results in array? in loop, print them to new file and then rename to first one.

Comment: @Idos: I see, that gets rid of the array problem. Is there any way to avoid the two nested for loops?

Comment: @LukášRutar: Thanks, but can I avoid the nested for loops, too?

Comment: @de_dust I doubt... since you need to compare each with each you gonna need two loops. 

Outer loop (B file) is nonogiable.

Since you only need one closest result, you could can come up with optimizations and early breaks in inner loop or "hashes" so you dont need to compare it to each record in it (And since there is only 300 lines in it, i would not bother), but two loops nevertheless.
I could only imagine eliminating inner loop if some sort approximation of shortest Levenshtein distance would be enough. You could use some heuristic then.